# Do you and your family apply for a German visa simultaneously if you have a job offer that entitles you to a Blue Card?

Tags: germany, family, blue-card

I have a job offer from a German company, and I am currently preparing my papers to apply for a visa (Blue card). I am married and would like to know if both my spouse and I can apply at the same time to the German consulate and move to Germany at the same time.

I can't find on the website of the German consulate serving my region any information about this. I only could find information about individual applications. Does the job offer I have as a skilled migrant allow me to include my wife in the visa application so we can move together, or will I have to move to Germany alone first and then apply for a family reunification visa for my wife?

Answer (score 2):

The [official web site of the Federal Office for Migration and Refugees](http://www.bamf.de/DE/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html) answers your question (please search for "Darf der Ehegatte eines Antragstellers gleichzeitig mit diesem nach Deutschland einreisen, um vor Ort den Familiennachzug zu beantragen?").

There it is mentioned that the visa **can** be also issues for wife/partner in the **"individual case"**. However, it is also mentioned that you **do not have** a "right to claim" for this and that you need to contact the embassy for your particular case.

Comment: I checked the link. Using Google translate it gives "If the applicant is in possession of a national visa and is in the prospect of being granted a Blue Card EU in Germany, a "spousal" visa may be issued to the "imprisoned" spouse in individual cases at that time. A claim for the simultaneous issuing of visas and entry does not exist. Please inform yourself as soon as possible at the responsible foreign representation." I don't get "A claim for the simultaneous issuing of visas and entry does not exist." Does it mean it is not possible?

Comment: This is the "right to claim" that I mentioned. It basically means that it will be decided in each individual case and that you should not treat it as your right, i.e. the embassy can indeed give you such "simultaneous" visa as a kind of a "goodwill", but you cannot insist on it. If you insist, they will deny it. So all that is written there is basically "ask your embassy, they can (but are not required to) give it to you".

Comment: Ok, that's clearer now. I will ask the embassy before submitting joint applications.