# I have a work permit visa from the employer in Germany- Berlin. Will my wife get a dependent visa?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit, blue-card, dependent-visa

Both me and my spouse are Indian nationals. I have a work permit from one of the employers in Germany.

*I have 3 questions* -

**1.** Is this work permit from the employer, limited only to this company? ie) With this work permit visa (assuming that is valid for a year from the German state), can i search for other companies as well?

**2.** Will my wife get a dependent visa along with my work permit visa ? 
 If so, can anyone help me with links or steps on how she can apply for Dependent visa.

**3.** Once she has a dependent visa, can that visa be converted to EU Blue card ? (Just like how I can convert from my work permit to EU visa by showing that i have some Euro's in my account or that i am a highly skilled worker)

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/change-company-on-an-eu-blue-card-visa

Comment: The wording of this question is very confusing, making a precise answer impossible. I assume that the OP has a **contract** offer from a employer, since employer's **don't** issue a work permit. Only based on the details (position, salary) of such a contract, can the type of D-Visa to apply for be determined. If a Visa has already been issued, what type of visa is it? If needed supply a redacted image of the visa. Otherwise such a question is a pure **guessing game**, which will not result in a reliable answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. The moment you leave the current employer your work permit becomes invalid. Yes you can definitely search for other job.
2. Yes she can. You both  can together apply i.e you for work visa and your wife dependent visa. Kindly check the german embassy website.
3. No. Not unless she meets all the requirements for a blue card. Kindly go through the eligibilty criteria for a Blue Card. You have to be highly qualified, skilled and must have a local contract. Merely showing a few 1000 euros in your bank account does not make you eligible for eu blue card.

Comment: While i leave the current company, how long can i stay in Germany with that visa? Will the validity of work visa be mentioned on my visa? and i see in some of the Quora links, that if i show that i am highly skilled and that i earn around 50-60 Euro annually, then i can apply for EU card?

Answer (score 0):

With no work contract I doubt if you can apply for Eu Blue card but if you have any offer and accept it then definitely. Do you have any offers or are searching for job? You must not have left your current job. You can go to the auslanderbehorde and tell them about your situation. And also you can talk to your current employer and request them not to invalidate your current visa, if they agree good.

Comment: I am currently employed in my home country-India, and i am in the process of getting my work permit for Germany from the employer. So wanted to check the process and eligibility to get EU card for me and my spouse! And what do u mean by - "...request them not to invalidate your current visa"?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is this work permit from the employer, limited only to this company? ie) With this work permit visa (assuming that is valid for a
>      year from the German state), can i search for other companies as well?

If you receive a work permit then it is limited to a single company for 2 years.  After this time and can get this restriction lifted (you have to apply for it) and you are then free to work for any employer in Germany.
If you want to change employer before this then you need to apply for a new work permit for that specific employer.

You are also able to convert this to a Blue card while you are in Germany as long as you meet the requirements.
But even a Blue card is limited to a specific employer for the first two years, and you can only change your job with permission from the Ausländerbehörde (ABH) / Immigration office.

If you qualify for a blue card then you should apply for that rather than a work permit.

> 2. Will my wife get a dependent visa along with my work permit visa ? If so, can anyone help me with links or steps on how she can apply for
>      Dependent visa.

Once you are in Germany you can apply for a family reunion visa.  But you must already be living in Germany before you can apply, and the application will take several months.

There are requirements that you must both meet, such as the requirements for health insurance for both of you, the size of the apartment, that you earn enough, and your wife will need basic German knowledge (A1 level).

See: https://www.germany-visa.org/family-reunion-visa/

> 3. Once she has a dependent visa, can that visa be converted to EU Blue card ? (Just like how I can convert from my work permit to EU
>      visa by showing that i have some Euro's in my account or that i am a
>      highly skilled worker)

No it doesn't work like that.
But, assuming she gets a family reunion visa and then lives in Germany then she will be able to work in Germany on this visa if she wants to with no issues.

Comment: Good answer except the part covering second question. It is definitely possible to apply for a kind of "family reunion" visa before entering Germany, if the OP is going to get a Blue Card, see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/13901/13223 for details